# Php table template for sql queries

Tags: php, mysql, templates

In a php inventory management application let's say I'm having two sql tables : **tblAcq** and **tblInvoice**. Both identical `(ID, Number, Note, Date)` but with different data.

I have two pages : **acq.php** and **invoice.php**. Both pages display a html table from a query `(SELECT * FROM tblX)`.

Because the table is identical on both pages and the only difference between the two is in the `FROM tblX (tblAcq or tblInvoice)`, is there any way I can make a `template` for the table (for example `orders.php`) and include it in `acq.php` and `invoice.php`?

I'm new to php and I can't figure this out because the table must be in a while clause

The code is something like this for **acq.php** page:

```
<?php
$sqlacq ="SELECT * FROM tblAcq";
$resultacq = $conn->query($sqlacq);
?>
       <table id="acq-tbl" class="tbl-qa" border="1">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-header" width="10%">AcqID</th>
                <th class="table-header">Data (an-luna-zi)</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqNumber</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqSupplier</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqNote</th>
                <th class="table-header">InStocLa</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php
        if ($resultacq->num_rows > 0) {
            while($rowacq = $resultacq->fetch_assoc()) {
           ?>
              <tr class="table-row" ondblclick="mySelection(event)">
                <td><?php echo $rowacq["AcqID"]; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'AcqDate','<?php echo $rowacq["AcqID"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $rowacq["AcqDate"]; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'AcqNumber','<?php echo $rowacq["AcqID"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $rowacq["AcqNumber"]; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'AcqSupplier','<?php echo $rowacq["AcqID"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $rowacq["AcqSupplier"]; ?></td>
                <td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,'AcqNote','<?php echo $rowacq["AcqID"]; ?>')" onClick="showEdit(this);"><?php echo $rowacq["AcqNote"]; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $rowacq["InStocLa"]; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id(<?php echo $rowacq["AcqID"]; ?>)"><img src="b_drop.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>
              </tr>
        <?php
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the content of the `saveToDatabase()` function in the onblur? Does that also have to chenge depending on the page?

Comment: keep a common page and add a function to retrieve data from the tables, pass the table name to the function

Comment: @Thaillie `saveToDatabase()` function uses a javascript and a separate php file for inline update of the database rows. I think would only need to point to a different php file to change the table that is updated

Comment: @Lucky Chingi - I'm not really sure how to do that, but I'll try to put some thought into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can embed html in php using echo statements.

```
<?php
$sqlacq ="SELECT * FROM tblAcq";
$resultacq = $conn->query($sqlacq);
?>
       <table id="acq-tbl" class="tbl-qa" border="1">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-header" width="10%">AcqID</th>
                <th class="table-header">Data (an-luna-zi)</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqNumber</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqSupplier</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqNote</th>
                <th class="table-header">InStocLa</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          <?php

        if ($resultacq->num_rows > 0) {
            while($rowacq = $resultacq->fetch_assoc()) {
              echo '<tr class="table-row" ondblclick="mySelection(event)">';
              echo '<td>'.$rowacq["AcqID"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqDate\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqDate"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqNumber\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqNumber"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqSupplier\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqSupplier"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqNote\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqNote"].'</td>';
              echo '<td>'.$rowacq["InStocLa"].'</td>';
              echo '<td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id('.$rowacq["AcqID"].')"><img src="b_drop.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>'
              echo "</tr>";
            }
          }

?>
```

EDIT:

In your case, `$rowacq` is an assoc array. So your final code will be,

```
<?php
$sqlacq ="SELECT * FROM tblAcq";
$resultacq = $conn->query($sqlacq);
?>
       <table id="acq-tbl" class="tbl-qa" border="1">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="table-header" width="10%">AcqID</th>
                <th class="table-header">Data (an-luna-zi)</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqNumber</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqSupplier</th>
                <th class="table-header">AcqNote</th>
                <th class="table-header">InStocLa</th>

              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
       <?php
        function table_print($rowacq) {
              echo '<tr class="table-row" ondblclick="mySelection(event)">';
              echo '<td>'.$rowacq["AcqID"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqDate\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqDate"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqNumber\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqNumber"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqSupplier\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqSupplier"].'</td>';
              echo '<td contenteditable="true" onBlur="saveToDatabase(this,\'AcqNote\',\''.$rowacq["AcqID"].'\')" onClick="showEdit(this);">'.$rowacq["AcqNote"].'</td>';
              echo '<td>'.$rowacq["InStocLa"].'</td>';
              echo '<td align="center"><a href="javascript:delete_id('.$rowacq["AcqID"].')"><img src="b_drop.png" alt="Delete" /></a></td>'
              echo "</tr>";

        }
       if ($resultacq->num_rows > 0) {
            while($rowacq = $resultacq->fetch_assoc()) {
                table_print($rowacq);
            }
       }
?>
```

Comment: Ok, but I still can't understand how can I generate two html tables (from two sql statements) without repeating the code. Let's say I want them to show on the same page to simplify the matter. How can I generate two html tables from two mysql tables without repeating the html code. I need exactly the same tables two times only difference is in the select FROM tblAcq and FROM tblInvoice.

Comment: Create a function with the loop and pass the assoc array as the parameter.

Comment: I don't really know how... what is the assoc array in this case?

Comment: Thank you I think it works. I'll have to do some testing but it seems to be what I am looking for.